# Apache is not starting. Servers not found OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, apache, operating-system, xampp, osx-yosemite

I am having problems after I installed XAMPP . it looks like something is missing. but is shows it works. It was working before until I had reinstall OS X Yosemite. Now, I can't start a new or existing wordpress projects. I don't see the button  to launch a new website or open existing websites as I used to do before.

It shows, It works ====>> http://screencast.com/t/vHbUlmJauQ  but apache is not starting. It doesn't start the servers.

Please watch the following video ====>> http://screencast.com/t/Bb2PpENSL

Someone could help me on Skype using team viewer? Please help.

Comment: Please ask this question at SuperUser. This has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Flagged to close as off-topic.

Comment: are you having fun by flagging other people's posts that are requesting for help?

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like you have the default os x apache running - in system preferences -> sharing -> web server. turn that off, and try and restart apache

you may need to use a different port than 80 as that sounds like it is in use on you macintosh computer

Comment: I reinstalled XAMPP and apache is working. but I can't access to phpMyAdmin . I get the following Error : Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed. It is not connecting to MySQL Database.

It would be very helpful if you share a screenshot of how to fix it. Please watch the following 30 seconds video http://screencast.com/t/AS9TH2g69

Thanks in advance